# Creating a pull request with autocomplete enabled Azure DevOps rest API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm struggling to figure out how to create a pull request with autocomplete enabled with using the API if someone can provide an example of the JSON posted to enable the autocomplete that would be awesome.

I've tried setting the `autoCompleteSetBy` Property and also have tried a whole bunch of settings within  `completionOptions` Property as well.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/298596/autocompletesetby-ignored-in-pull-request-rest-api.html) helps...

Comment: Agree with Shayki, the documentation here seems unfortunately wrong. I test the Create PR rest api, the autoConpleteSetBy is no useful. But this response body can work in Pull Request - Update rest api.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't create a Pull Request with autocomplete enabled when you use the [Create PR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) rest API. you can only update a current PR with autocomplete enabled with the [Pull Requests - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1), so you need to create the PR, take the new ID and then update it.

The basic body is to specify the `autoCompleteSetBy` with the ID of the user who actually runs the API:

```
"autoCompleteSetBy":  {
                          "id":  "dsafasf-41531tf-safsaf-24124fas-sfasfasf"
                      }
```

You can also add additional parameters with `completionOptions` like squash merge and more, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#gitpullrequestcompletionoptions).

If you want to automate of creating Pull Requests process you can install the [Create Pull Request](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShaykiAbramczyk.CreatePullRequest) extension.

Comment: what do you mean with "the user who actually runs the API"

I am getting athe following error: "Invalid pull request auto complete set by id. Valid values are either the current user identity id, or an empty guid (to unset auto complete)"

Comment: How do you run the script? in build? locally?

Comment: I was running it in a pipeline within Azure DevOps. I managed to create the PR, but never to set the autocomplete. 

In the end I made it work with your extension, but I wanted to understand what was wrong with my API call. Not sure if I was not picking the right ID, or if I was getting this error because the "Server Build User" I was using didn't have on the repo, besides creating a PR. I had to fix that before having your extension up and running. 

Anyway, it is working now! Thank you for the great job with the extension!

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned in another reply - you indeed need to first create pull request and after that update it's status.

If you're looking for some ready made code - then I can suggest to take a look on following library in C#:

https://github.com/lvermeulen/Conductor/tree/main

Especially what you're asking is happening in this line:

https://github.com/lvermeulen/Conductor/blob/3faa1ecb5f31462a999a84661077f04eb26df526/src/Conductor.AzureDevOps.Api/AzureDevOpsApiWrapper.cs#L93

Example of demo application can be found from it's unit tests - which is outdated, but still shows how it should work in theory:

https://github.com/lvermeulen/Conductor/blob/3faa1ecb5f31462a999a84661077f04eb26df526/test/Conductor.AzureDevOps.Api.Tests/AzureDevOpsApiWrapperShould.cs

Unfortunately I was not able to find any nuget package for `Conductor.AzureDevOps.Api.dll`. Created a [ticket](https://github.com/lvermeulen/Conductor/issues/1) on issue.